# Odd corruption of byte string in PDF annotations, won't decode in utf-8 (pdfminer)

Tags: python, utf-8, decode, pdfminer, pdftotext

I have a strange issue popping up when attempting to scrape the links from a pdf file. The link appears as 'http://www.mbc.ca.gov/Licensees/License_Renewal/Physician_Survey.aspx' in the pdf file. However, it comes out as:

```
b'http://www.mbc.ca.gov/Licensees/License_Renewal/Physici\xe9C@|\xf2\xefw\x0e\xd3\x8d>X\x0f\xe7\xc6'
```

when performing a resolve() method on the PDFObjRef. Why the sudden corruption in the link there? Almost looks like a newline or something that got interpreted as a byte. Also, why is this even a byte string if it's clearly human readable? Is this normal behavior for pdfminer?

It gives this error when attempting to decode that byte string with utf-8:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 55: invalid continuation byte
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a goner. The script works with all pdfs I've encountered but this one. So unless someone can come up with a reason that pdfminer would get a weird/corrupt encoding about 40-60 characters into a byte string, this is FUBAR.